# sharepoint get the display form with content using jquery get functionality

Tags: display-form, form-customization

we have a requirement to get the contents of the display form url

how do we achieve it ?

additional info: The form is customized using hilly billy

Things which we have tried

```
$.get("**listurl**/DispForm.aspx?ID=100", function(data) {
  var foo = jQuery("<div></div>").html(data).find(".viewrapper").html();
  jQuery(".viewrapper").append(foo);
  console.log(foo);
});
```

This would just show up the hillbilly html layout with no content in it

Comment: If you want to get a value of one or more fields, you shuold rather use rest api.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? If you need to display that DispForm in popup for example, you may add `?IsDlg=1`in URL